# Duplicate BinData Field on MongoDB console

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure like this.

```
doc {
   "_id": "customized str id"
   "data": "BinData(0,"base64String");
}

db.test.find("_id":"1234-test").forEach(
    function(doc) {
      db.test.insert({_id":"1235-test"},{"data":doc.data});
    }
);
```

I also tried.

```
db.test.find("_id":"1234-test").forEach(
    function(doc) {
      db.test.insert({_id":"1235-test"},{"data":new BinData(0,doc.data)});
      or db.test.insert({_id":"1235-test"},{"data":{"$binary":doc.data,"$type":0}});
    }
);
```

Result return except binary field.
Is there any way to copy binary field to duplicated document?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things wrong here.

First, insert() takes a single argument, which is the document to insert. (Did you perhaps want update/upsert?) So you want:

```
db.test.insert({_id":"1235-test", "data": doc.data})
```

Second, the data is already a binary BSON type when it's coming from the document, so you don't need to encode it or wrap it as BinData or anything.

```
> db.test.find({"_id": "1234-test"}).next().data
BinData(0,"base64String")
> typeof(db.test.find({"_id": "1234-test"}).next().data)
object
```

So, to copy it from one doc to a new doc:

```
db.test.find({"_id": "1234-test"}).forEach( function(doc) {
    db.test.insert({"_id": "1235-test" , "data": doc.data})
})
```

Comment: My syntax was wrong. Thank you for your kind answer.